# unable to create a release file for my adobe air app

Tags: apache-flex, air

while trying to create the release file I am seeing error creating AIR file: 102: ERROR, http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/1.5

Please advise how to fix it?

Comment: We need more info.  What version of AIR are you using?  What version of Flex?  How are you trying to create a release file (Flash Builder?  command line tools?  Something else?)?  Are you able to run the project in debug mode?  Is that the full error?

Comment: the adobe flex ide version is 3 . i am using the release build option from the ide to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure, but I am guessing your namespace does not match the selected SDK. 1.5 is VERY old. 3.4 was released a few weeks ago and if you are running at least Flash Builder 4.5, the lowest SDK you can have is either 3.0 or 3.1. Figure out which AIR SDK you are using, and change it in your App Descriptor file (AppName/src/AppName-app.xml).

Is that the entire error you are receiving?

Comment: yes thats the entire error i am receiving. the flex builder ide i am using is Adobe Flex Builder 3

Comment: I have no experience with Flex Builder, but it might be wise to update your AIR SDK (if possible) and match the namespace (http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/1.5) in your App descriptor to match the new SDK (http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/VERSIONNUMBERHERE). I get this issue all the time (I am switching between AIR SDKs frequently due to unique issues with each), and it is almost always the namespace not matching the selected AIR SDK